# rails devise trigger lock of lockable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

By default, n failed attempts to **log in** locks the user's account.

I want to also have a method call to lock the account, or at least trigger the code which says "hey this account has n failed attempts I should lock it".

I can increment the number of failed attempts, but this does not trigger the account getting locked.

Example uses: User must give current password to change email, n failed attempts locks account. Or user is super paranoid and wants to have a button which locks their account (and boots all users out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lockable module adds `lock_access!`, `unlock_access!` and `access_locked?` (amongst other methods) to your user model.  You should be able to call them directly, or call them from other methods which add further logic (e.g. your example of n attempts to give password to change email address).  `lock_access!` also takes an option in devise 3.2.3+ which skips sending email instructions if you want.  See:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.2.3/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb